# Increase max allowed header size when hitting an S3 bucket endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am `curl`-ing an endpoint that does a redirection to an S3-bucket.

I must pass some large headers to my request which fails because the max header size is exceeded:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge</Code>
   <Message>Your request header section exceeds the maximum allowed size.</Message>
   <MaxSizeAllowed>8192</MaxSizeAllowed>
   <RequestId>AP394DD4D4F133</RequestId>
   <HostId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is there a way to tweak this at the S3 level & increase the maximum allowed header size?

Comment: So it is directly downloading from the S3 bucket? Or is this going via API gateway etc.? How are you exactly downloading(?) this file

Comment: It is not downloading. Just a GET request with huge headers

Comment: GET request to what?

Comment: To the bucket hosting a static site

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: yes it is unfortunately

Comment: facing this issue as well, does not seem to be a solution anywhere.

Comment: how did you increase the header size?