# RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge 8192 issue when cookie size is large

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

I'm getting the following XML when I add more cookies in my website.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge</Code>
<Message>Your request header section exceeds the maximum allowed size.</Message>
<MaxSizeAllowed>8192</MaxSizeAllowed>
<RequestId>GTA11111111</RequestId>
<HostId>Test111</HostId>
</Error>
```

I got the same issue for a distribution in cloudfront and I was able to solve it using [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73554409/8417783)

I'm facing the same issue in a Cloudflare distribution but I'm unable to find the way to update the legacy cache settings (If that is the correct way to handle this).

Where is this limit in defined in cloudflare? As per my understanding, this comes as default as I could not find anything relevant in page rules or related configurations.

[image]